# PySpark: aggregate() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: apache-spark

Removed text due to this being due to a simple typo issue (the accepted answer gives the correct solution). I will mention that if anyone is using the "Learning Spark" O`Reilly Book from 2015, the typo described is actually present in Example 3-35. Moral of the story: don't trust that textbook code to be syntactically correct. Pay attention.

Comment: the first lambda isn't closed properly. please double check next time

Comment: Well, this is majorly embarrassing. Turns out my linter wasn't enabled in my editor either, hopefully this should prevent future questions like this from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at your syntax.

Here's the corrected version a bit more structured.

```
import pyspark as ps


conf = ps.SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = ps.SparkContext(conf = conf)
nums = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])

f1 = lambda acc, value: (acc[0] + value, acc[1] + 1)
f2 = lambda acc1, acc2: (acc1[0] + acc2[0], acc1[1] + acc2[1]

nums.aggregate((0, 0), f1, f2)
```